# Найти самый длинный палиндром из строки удалением любого количества символов

Tags: python, строки

Требуется найти самый длинный палиндром P, получающийся из данной строки S удалением любого (возможно, нулевого) количества символов.

Во входных данных записана строка S состоящая из строчных английских букв. Длина S не превосходит 1 000 символов.
Выведите искомый палиндром. Если таких палиндромов несколько, выведите любой из них.

Вход: anna
Выход: anna

Вход: perevorot
Выход: ror

Возникли проблемы с данной задачей. Я нашел алгоритм решения тут - https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5, но не могу понять как находится 4 диагональ двухмерного массива и все следующие за ней (за первую диагональ я считаю главную). Можете пожалуйста подробнее объяснить, или приложить какой-нибудь другой алгоритм, который по вашему мнению проще, желательно с кодом (на питоне).

Comment: Переставлять буквы нельзя? Только удалять?

Comment: Насколько я понял - нельзя

Comment: Так на той странице же даже код есть

Comment: Он не на питоне

Comment: Он ничем не отличается от питона. Стоит поучиться разбираться в псевдокоде.

Answer (score 2):

"Перевел" код с приведенной вами страницы на `python3`:

```py
def palSubSeq(L, string, left, right):
    if L[left][right] == -1:
        if string[left] == string[right]:
            L[left][right] = palSubSeq(L, string, left+1, right-1) + 2
        else:
            L[left][right] = max(palSubSeq(L, string, left+1, right) , palSubSeq(L, string, left, right-1))
    return L[left][right]

def palChars(L, palindrome, left, right, palLeft, palRight):
    while left <= right:
        if left==right and L[left][right]==1:
            palindrome[palLeft] = string[left]
            palLeft += 1
            left += 1
        else:
            if string[left] == string[right]:
                palindrome[palLeft] = string[left]
                palLeft += 1
                left += 1

                palindrome[palRight] = string[right]
                palRight -= 1
                right -= 1
            else:
                if L[left+1][right] >= L[left][right-1]:
                    left += 1
                else:
                    right -= 1

def search_pal(string):
    N = len(string)
    palindrome = ['_' for _ in range(N)]
    L = [[-1] * N for _ in range(N)]

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if i==j:
                L[i][j] = 1
            elif i>j:
                L[i][j] = 0
    palSubSeq(L, string, 0, N-1)
    palChars(L, palindrome, 0, N-1, 0, L[0][N-1])
    return ''.join(filter('_'.__ne__, palindrome)) 

string = 'oro'
if string == string[::-1]:
    palindrome = string[::-1]
else:
    palindrome = search_pal(string)
print(palindrome)
```

Comment: Если изначально входная строка равна палиндрому, то выдается ошибка

Comment: @ВалерийТарасов исправил

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно использовать функцию `combinations` из библиотеки `itertools`, чтобы перебрать комбинации из N символов слова, не меняя при этом порядок их следования. Ну и в качестве N берём числа от 1 до длины слова, ну и потом ищем среди найденных таким образом палиндромов те, у которых максимальная длина.

```
from itertools import combinations
word = 'perevorot'
pal = [w for i in range(1, len(word)+1) for w in combinations(word, i) if tuple(reversed(w)) == w]
m = max(map(len, pal))
print([''.join(w) for w in pal if len(w) == m])
```

Вывод:

```
['ere', 'rer', 'rvr', 'ror', 'oro']
```

**Обновление**

Добавил немного оптимизированную версию, которая ищет начиная с максимальной длины и прекращает поиск с первым найденным палиндромом:

```
from itertools import combinations

def find_max_palyndrome(word):
    for i in range(len(word), 0, -1):
        for w in combinations(word, i):
            if tuple(reversed(w)) == w:
                return ''.join(w)

print(find_max_palyndrome('anna'))
print(find_max_palyndrome('perevorot'))
```

Вывод:

```
anna
ere
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант, но работает слишком долго

Comment: @ВалерийТарасов Добавил немного оптимизированную версию, сильно сократил поиск вариантов

Comment: Стало немного лучше, но если задана действительно длинная последовательность, то затрачивается много времени на перебор всех комбинаций.

Comment: @ВалерийТарасов Ну, дальше только хитрости какие-то придумывать алгоритмические